# getTable() does not work in core code on core table

Tags: ce-1.8.0.0

In `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Report_Bestsellers_Collection::_initSelect()` on Line 138

```
$mainTable = $this->getTable('sales/bestsellers_aggregated_yearly');
```

Magento throws an error: `Can't retrieve entity config: sales/bestsellers_aggregated_yearly` but table `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly` does exist.

Why does Magento not find this table?

I did a Magento update from ce-1.4.0.1 that might have messed up something...

**Update**

`getTable()` is calling `Mage_Core_Model_Resource::getTableName()` and this looks like this:

```
    $parts = explode('/', $modelEntity);
    if (isset($parts[1])) {
        list($model, $entity) = $parts;
        $entityConfig = false;
        if (!empty(Mage::getConfig()->getNode()->global->models->{$model}->resourceModel)) {
            $resourceModel = (string)Mage::getConfig()->getNode()->global->models->{$model}->resourceModel;
            $entityConfig  = $this->getEntity($resourceModel, $entity);
        }

        if ($entityConfig && !empty($entityConfig->table)) {
            $tableName = (string)$entityConfig->table;
        } else {
            Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('core')->__('Can\'t retrieve entity config: %s', $modelEntity));
        }
```

In `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/config.xml` the correct table is defined as `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly` with the config path:

```
/config/global/models/sales_resource/entities/bestsellers_aggregated_yearly
```

To find modules messing with this config i did:

```
grep -R "bestsellers_aggregated_yearly" app/
```

And found only core files:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Report/Bestsellers/Collection.php
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/*
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/config.xml
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem was a module's `etc/config.xml` which was overwriting resourceModel of `<sales>`:

```
    <models>
        <sales>
            <class>Mage_Sales_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>sales_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </sales>
         ...
```

It was a copy of the old Sales config that did not include `bestsellers_aggregated_yearly` nor any other new stuff. I removed this bad config completely because it contained no change compared to the sales config in the old Magento core.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something got messed up in the sales module or by a module overriding `Mage_Sales`. Have a look at the `config.xml` of `Mage_Sales` where the alias `sales` is defined. (Xpath: `/config/global/models/sales_resource/entities/bestsellers_aggregated_yearly`)

Then check if any custom modul destorys something in here, you can get closer by dumping the full XML config. (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11784811/inspect-config-xml-tree-magento-generates)